# Can I only replace the cocos2dx 64bit files?

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-2.x, iphone-64bit

I have my game in cocos2dx 2.0 and we know it does not contain 64-bit support, but we have cocos2dx 2.2.6 with 64-bit support, can I only replace the main files from cocos2dx 2.2.6 that makes the cocos2d 2.0 64-bit supported?

Please help me because my project is so big to perform all the changes.

Yes this is a stupid question but I want to give it a try to save time.
Please help, and sorry if I didn't explained well.

Comment: I was trying to do that with cocos 2.2.3 and it not worked for me. So you have to create a new project in cocos 2.2.6, configure it, copy resources from old version project and bind all functions in cocos you did in previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there Is no Other Way.
You Must have to transfer or copy all your file in version of coco2dx 2.6.6

You just copy and paste might be an hours of work